# What is this glassware for a distillation apparatus called?

Tags: equipment, distillation

I'm messing around with building a solar distillation apparatus, and one of the parts I think I need looks kind of like the following, except I have no idea what it is called (and thus can't look it up to see if that site even sells them).
[image: this]

So, can anyone tell me what this thing is commonly called?

Comment: We called them kugelrohr bulbs.

Comment: It's part of a Kugelrohr distillation apparatus. It is more sophisticated and more expensive but more efficient for fractional distillation especially for higher boiling point compounds and probably easier to use when you know what you are doing. This is a link with a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o34psrncdB8)  @ron you are so fast! I initially thought it looked like a glass column head/reservoir...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "A" on the glassware gives it away as an Aldrich glassware component;
and Ron is correct calling it a Kugelrohr bulb. It is actually a *single bulb ball tube*.

This specific item can be found in the [catalogue at Aldrich's website](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/labware/labware-products.html?TablePage=17215996)